# How do you make an app that displays a logo for a couple of seconds then a text sentence on the screen?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

How do you make an app that displays a logo for a couple of seconds then a text sentence on the screen?

I want to make the app in Android Studio in Java, the goal is that once the app is opened, any sort of logo will appear for 5 seconds, then a sentence will appear then that's it.

I already tried to use the already provided code presets by Android Studio but the problem is, I have no idea how do I do the things that I previously mentioned... I really need help on this.

Any help will be very appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have these two Activities namely:

1. SplashScreenActivity
2. MainActivity

The former has an [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) to display a logo. The latter has a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) to display a sentence. You should learn to make these at first.

Once you have those Activities, then learn to use [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) to switch between the former and the latter.